# Is it harmful for power transformer operate without load?

Tags: transformer, safety, current-transformer

I open chest of slide projector and there are power transformer from ~220V to ~6V and directly connected light bulb.

If light was burned out is it harmful for power transformer operate without load?

Are any special danger for user in that case?

Comment: Answered, but this seems off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't harmful at all.  There will be a bit of wasted power, and some generated heat, but it won't harm the transformer.

There isn't any more danger for the user then if the bulb were still connected and functioning.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough there is a case for expecting small problems when the transformer is not connected to a load.

I might add that ALL transformers will do this to a greater or lesser extent. Core saturation is slightly worse off-load because the terminal voltage applied to the primary is (bar a few millivolts) directly feeding the magnetization inductance i.e. there is no load current in the primary to drop a few percent of this voltage across the primary leakage resistance and inductance.

I have witnessed this on one occasion on a 1kW transformer. As the power was applied when the transformer secondary was disconnected a slightly higher peak inrush of magnetization current occurred and tripped a breaker maybe 1 in 5 times. It never tripped the breaker when on full load because of the volt drop in the primary leakage impedance.

We did some analasis and proved that it was more likely to trip the breaker when the voltage was applied at a zero cross and this is a recognized symptom of inrush current caused by both the application at zero degrees combined with core saturation.

S, I guess it's not harmful but certainly annoying. However if this transformer were on a supply also used by medical equipment it could be deamed to be harmful.